# map is not visible in tabs when back button pressed

Tags: android, google-maps, tabs

In my application i displayed the map using the following xml code.

```
<fragment 
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

In first activity button click i am using the code to display the mapactivity.

```
            Intent intent=new Intent(getParent(),mapActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

             View view = MapTab.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("notification",intent).getDecorView();  
                // Again, replace the view  
             MapTab.group.replaceView(view);
```

And in my MapActivity class i am using the following code to display the map.

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
         map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
         map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
         map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
         bounds=new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(33.66535378579427, -117.90596008300781),
                new LatLng( 33.66890364313455, -117.89649188518524));
         BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.categorymap);
         GroundOverlayOptions groundOverlay = new GroundOverlayOptions()
         .image(image)
         .positionFromBounds(bounds)
         .transparency(0.1f)
         .anchor(0.1f, 0.5f);
         map.addGroundOverlay(groundOverlay);
```

By using this code the map is displayed correctly.In MapActivity class in button click i am using the following code to display the DetailsActivty class.

```
        Intent intent=new Intent(getParent(),DetailsActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

         View view = MapTab.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("notification",intent).getDecorView();  
            // Again, replace the view  
         MapTab.group.replaceView(view);
```

In DetailsActivity class in back button i have written the following code.

```
MapTab.group.onBackPressed();
```

So by using this the present activity(DetalmapActivity) is finished and previous activity(MapActivity) is displayed but map is not visible.the banlk screen is visible.And this is the maptab class.

```
public class MapTab  extends ActivityGroup{

   // Keep this in a static variable to make it accessible for all the nesten activities, lets them manipulate the view  
   public static MapTab group;  

   // Need to keep track of the history if you want the back-button to work properly, don't use this if your activities requires a lot of memory.  
   public static  ArrayList<View> history;  
   public static View view;

   @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

          this.history = new ArrayList<View>();           
          group = this; 

          Window wd= getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("History",new Intent(this,MapActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
          view=wd.getDecorView();
          replaceView(view);
      }  

   public void replaceView(View v) {  
               // Adds the old one to history  
    Log.e("View is","added");

       history.add(v);     
       //Log.e("arraylilst size is",String.valueOf(history.size()));    
       // Changes this Groups View to the new View.  
        this.setContentView(v);  
   }  

   public void back() {  
       if(history.size() > 0) {  
            history.remove(history.size()-1);  
            setContentView(history.get(history.size()-1));  
       }else {  
            finish();  
       }  
    }  

   @Override  
    public void onBackPressed() { 
       Tabs.check_tab=true;
    try{
        Log.e("onBackPressed","workinggg");
        MapTab.group.back();
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        finish();
    }


       return;  
   }  
}
```

So please guide me what i have done mistake in my code.

Comment: setup map again in your activity `onResume()`

Comment: thank you for your response. onResume method is didn't call

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: what is the problem in tabs

Comment: I agree with what @SimplePlan has said, you haven't setup an onResume method, from what you are saying the same situation would arise if the app was interrupted by say a telephone call, the map wouldn't appear as there is no way for it to resume